# How to modify letter overlap axis map ggplot2

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

Please note how the letters overlap on the x-axis.
Is there a way to change this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPgli.png)

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example of how you created the figure in the body of your question. We'll need both data and code. Tips on how to do this are found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example You'll need to reduce the number of axis labels to make them not overlap, but how you do that depends on your data and how the plot was created.

Comment: You could adjust the axis.text.x parameters theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))

Comment: Hi Miguel there are lots of good suggestions for how to fix this in the answers to the linked duplicate question. If you are struggling to apply these, please feel free to ask a more detailed question including the code you tried, and explain where you got stuck. Good luck!